# SVN Post-Commit Hook to Publish Website?

Tags: linux, shell, svn, amazon-ec2

I've got an SVN instance installed on a free EC2 AWS server.  In short: I'm using LAMP.

Using what I read in [this article](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/) and encountered the "you need a TTY" error as mentioned in the comments.  I followed the [second resource](http://maymay.net/blog/2010/03/17/how-to-work-around-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo-without-sacrificing-security/) and it cleared the error message, but doesn't seem to be executing the script.  When I manually run the script, however, it works.

Any clue what I'm missing?

When I followed the second resource to fix the TTY error I changed the contents of my /svn/repository/hooks/post-commit script from:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/local/bin/svn-post-commit-update-mysite 1>&2
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
su –session-command=”/usr/local/bin/svn-post-commit-update-mysite 1>&2″ dynamic &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First possible issue:

You cannot rely on the value of the $PATH variable inside the hook. This means you need to specify complete paths for all executables.

In particular, "su" is a program located in "/bin/sh" in most distributions. To be sure, type

`type su`

Next possible issue:

Is your subversion server being run as root? `su` will try to ask for password if run by other users, and will fail if it's not being run interactively - even if the user is in the sudoers file!

If you are using Apache+DAV, this means the apache service must be run as root for this to work (instead of www-data), which is a *serious* security problem.

You probably don't need to use `su` or `sudo` at all if all of the files are owned by the same user (www-data, for instance). You can change the ownership of the site files with something like

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/<my-project>`

And then remove the `sudo` and `su` from both the hook and the svn-post-commit-update-mysite file.

Comment: Changing ownership and removing the sudo/su commands from the files worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that something in your script depends on the PATH environment variable.  Subversion runs hooks in an empty environment for security reasons.  So you need to either setup the environment in your shell script or use absolute paths.

You might want to read the [Subversion book entry on implementing hook scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).  The particular issue I mentioned is explained in the information block.